# Horizontal click and drag scroller for multiple sections help, works for only one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling

So I have a horizontal scrolling feature which works great in JS but only for one section with the classname, any other section that shares the same classname it doesn't replicate the same effects for. How can I make it so it works for every section that has the class name. You can see it in action on my website here where the quick links scrolls fine when you click but the other horizontally scrolling sections dont. Thank you - https://tutoryou.uixweb.dev/

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.scroller-div');
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;

let startDragging = function (e) {
  mouseDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
};
let stopDragging = function (event) {
  mouseDown = false;
};

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!mouseDown) { return; }
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
});
// Add the event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First change this:

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.scroller-div');
```

To this:

```
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller-div');
```

`querySelector` will stop after finding the first element matching your selector while [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return a list of all the elements matching your selector.

Once you do that, you will need to loop through all the sliders and add the event listener to each one. So your code becomes wrapped in a `forEach` loop:

```
sliders.forEach(slider => {
  let mouseDown = false;
  let startX, scrollLeft;

  let startDragging = function (e) {
    mouseDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  };
  let stopDragging = function (event) {
    mouseDown = false;
  };

  slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!mouseDown) { return; }
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const scroll = x - startX;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
  });
  // Add the event listeners
  slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
  slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
  slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tired this but it still isn't working, any other ideas?

Comment: Still not working unfortunately, I just realised I missed out a bit of code at the bottom in my post which I have since edited, don't know if this might help?
// Add the event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);

Comment: Yes those need to be included inside the loop as well. I've updated my answer to include them in. Don't forget to change the variable name from "slider" to "sliders" at the start.

Answer (score 0):

for smooth scrolling (no jump effect) you have to create variables inside `forEach()`

```
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller-div');

sliders.forEach(slider=>{
    let startX, scrollLeft;

    let startDragging = function(e) {
        mouseDown = true;
        startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    };
    let stopDragging = function(event) {
        mouseDown = false;
    };
    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!mouseDown) {
            return;
        }
        const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        const scroll = x - startX;
        slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
    }
    );
    // Add the event listeners
    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
}
);
```